# Convert string 06/12/2015 12:00 PM to date format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

How to convert string `06/12/2015 12:00 PM` to date format (milliseconds) in JavaScript. `new Date('06/12/2015 12:00 PM')` gives me `invalid date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```
Date.parse('06/12/2015 12:00 PM');
```